# Update a table in MySQL with all data from another table

Tags: mysql, database, join, sql-update

I have 3 tables: ak_class, ak_objects, ak_class_object
ak_class:

```
class_id | class_description | class_name |
1        | some description  | some name  |
2        | some description  | some name  |
3        | some description  | some name  | 

ak_objects: 
object_id | object_description | object_name |
1         | some description   | some name   |
2         | some description   | some name   |
3         | some description   | some name   | 

ak_class_object: 
class_object_id | class_id | object_id  |
1               | 1        | 1          |
2               | 2        | 2          |
3               | 3        | 3          |
```

I need to fill in the `ak_class_object` with a class_id from `ak_class` table and object_id from `ak_objects` table.

The question is how can I update (I need to update as there is some wrong data currently) the class_id from the ak_class table with all the ids? I was thinking of using it with JOIN ut I don't know which id to use to Join them as class_id is only to be updated

UPD: I was trying to do it like this, but it didn't work:

```
DELIMITER $$
DROP PROCEDURE class_object_1$$
CREATE PROCEDURE class_object_1()
BEGIN
DECLARE i INT DEFAULT 0;
WHILE (i < 250000) DO
UPDATE ak_class_object 
SET class_id = SELECT DISTINCT class_id from ak_class, object_id = SELECT DISTINCT class_id from ak_objects;
SET i = i + 1;
END WHILE;
END$$
```

Answer (score 0):

I am writing the generic syntax, change the table names and column name as per your requirements.

```
update table1 inner join table2
on table1.id = table2.fk_id
set table1.column = table1.columnUpdated
```

Comment: Yes, i was thinking about joins, but on which id can I join them? I mean the common ids are class_id but they are the ones I need to update

Comment: if the data is incorrect, how would to decide the key on which you will compare 2 rows in the tables..?

Comment: That's what I'm talking about :) I need to upate data. There is no specific relation, I just need all data from one table to another table in simple words.